# Bootstrap tour start button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I use bootstrap in my site and to explain my site I would like to use [bootstrap tour](http://bootstraptour.com/). I have implement this in my test page and work fine. But the tour start when load the page, and I want starting a tour when click a button. I have follow this [article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/walk-users-through-your-website-with-bootstrap-tour--webdesign-17942) to implement my bootstrap tour.

This is a javascript of the bootstrap tour demo:

```
(function(){

    var tour = new Tour({
        storage : false
    });

    tour.addSteps([
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-one",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Welcome to our landing page!",
        content: "This tour will guide you through some of the features we'd like to point out."
      },
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-two",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Main navigation",
        content: "Here are the sections of this page, easily laid out."
      },
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-three",
        placement: "top",
        backdrop: true,
        title: "Main section",
        content: "This is a section that you can read. It has valuable information."
      },

    ]);

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();

}());
```

and this is the html section:

```
<div class="content-section-a tour-step tour-step-one"> One <br>

<div class="content-section-a tour-step tour-step-two"> Two <br>

<div class="content-section-a tour-step tour-step-three"> Three <br>
```

How to start my tour by click a button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change it to restart and it works.

`$("#start-tour").click(function() {
    tour.restart();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `tour.start();` when you click the button, and not on page load. Assuming your startbutton has the id `start-tour`. This snippet can be placed within `(function() { ... })`

```
$("#start-tour").click(function() {
    tour.start();
});
```

Comment: I have add this in my page:
<script>
$("#start-tour").click(function() {
    tour.init();
});
</script>

and this button: <button class = "btn" id ="start-tour">Start</button>

but not work

Comment: How to switch off the script in the loading page time?

Comment: In addition to what you have done you will have to include jQuery and remove tour.init(); from your code.

Comment: I have jquery <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and I have remove the tour.init() but not Work

Comment: Can you post a complete script with button?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have access to my computer at the moment. Have you placed the snippet at the end of your anonymous function?

Comment: Yes I have add at the end of my function but not work

Comment: It would seem I have missunderstood the library. Use the updated snippet in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132234/discussion-between-script-coded-and-frankie).

Answer (score 0):

first we write our operations to a function. Here it is important to write the definition of the tour outside the function.

```
var tour = new Tour();    

  function StartTour(){
      tour = new Tour({
        storage : false
      });

    tour.addSteps([
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-one",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Welcome to our landing page!",
        content: "This tour will guide you through some of the features we'd like to point out."
      },
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-two",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Main navigation",
        content: "Here are the sections of this page, easily laid out."
      },
      {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-three",
        placement: "top",
        backdrop: true,
        title: "Main section",
        content: "This is a section that you can read. It has valuable information."
      },

    ]);

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start(true);
}
```

Then we call StartTour function in the button click function.

```
  $(".tour-step").click(function() {
    StartTour(); 
   });
```